# How to get webcam working in VirtualBox

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, drivers, webcam

I am running a dual-boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu LTS 20.04. On the Windows partition, the webcam works without any problems. But in the Ubuntu partition the webcam does not work, shows in neither "Cheese" or "guvcview". My PC model is a Thinkpad X1 Tablet Gen 2.

Since I know that my webcam is not dead, it is frusturating... and using VirtualBox to run Windows on Ubuntu also does not work.

I am aware that my webcam does not have a Linux driver.

I have tried:

- The webcam does not show up in `lsusb`
- I have tried installing the extenstion package for webcam passthrough, but it does not help.
- `$ VBoxManage list webcams` shows 0 Video Input devices.
- I have also tried installing the necessary drivers from Lenovo's webpage (In the virtual machine).

*PS. If some of you magically find a driver that support my webcam, feel free to tell me... in all honesty I would rather have a working webcam on Ubuntu and not have to use a virtual machine at all.*

Answer (score 1):

(This is a blind answer that goes by the documentation only.)

First enter in Ubuntu the command `v4l-info` and see if the result
is something like "Intel IPU3 CIO2". If this succeeds, it means that
the hardware is detected.

Then follow the article
[Camera Support](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Camera-Support).
Although meant for the Microsoft Surface devices, these devices employ
the same camera as yours.

This is just a summary of the steps, details and links are to be found
in the post:

- Kernel patches may be required as described.
- In the file `/etc/default/grub` add to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT the
  parameter `acpi_enforce_resources=lax`, perhaps like this:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_enforce_resources=lax"
  ```
- The file `/lib/firmware/intel/ipu3-fw.bin` is required at kernel
  boot time to support loading of the IPU3 IMGU device.
- Install `libcamera` and dependencies, from source if required.

Comment: Okay, good news... `v4l-info` does actually show Intel IPU3 CIO2! But.. I cannot understand what to do with the third bullet point here, I think I managed to install the firmware-misc-nonfree repo, but when I try `grep -f irci_irci_ecr-master_20161208_0213_20170112_1500.bin` there is no file or directory with that name.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I never executed this procedure, so cannot help too much. All I can do is point you to the project that solved the problem for some people with the same computer model.

Comment: I have a Microsoft Surface 7 with Windows 11 Pro and lubuntu 22.04.4 in VirtualBox 7.0.12, and I get:

    open /dev/video0: No such file or directory

Do I have any chance to use my webcam in lubuntu?

Comment: @TheDareGuy: Better ask this as a separate question.